# How to use filename(s) if provided or stdin if not provided with argparse

Tags: python

I Have a code that is supposed to except either a -f / --filenames  and if -f option wasn't provided it should use the string/sentence, etc from STDIN.

```
argparse.add_argument("-f", metavar='FILE', nargs='*', 
      type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
```

Comment: This just gives you a filename which you still have to open. I'd suggest a function which processes the input, to which you would pass either the file handle or sys.stdin

Comment: An example to what you mean will be great if possible.